# What is the difference between sceneView.delegate and sceneView.session.delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am reading the code below.

https://github.com/tukuyo/rakumaruCardMan/blob/master/rakutencard-Man/ViewController.swift

```
    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.session.delegate = self
```

The code does not work without `sceneView.delegate = self`, but `sceneView.session.delegate = self` seems to work without error even if commented out.

So what is the reason of writing `sceneView.session.delegate = self?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sceneView` delegate is of type [ARSCNViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate), while the `session` delegate is of type [ARSessionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate). As you can see in the documentation, they provide different information through their methods, but they also provide some overlapping functionality, since both extend [ARSessionObserver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionobserver).

You will want to implement `ARSCNViewDelegate` only when you're working with `ARSCNView`, which is the case of the linked project. Most of the methods provided by this delegate are related to updates on the objects displayed by the renderer (SceneKit). So, when you're using `ARSCNView`, SceneKit and ARKit are tied together. When ARKit session (`sceneView.session`) is updated, the renderer is informed, and then it is updated, triggering methods from `ARSCNViewDelegate`. For example, when an anchor is added by ARKit, and a node is created associated with that anchor, [renderer(_:didAdd:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate/2865794-renderer) will be called.

As for `ARSessionDelegate`, you will want to implement it when you need to know about anchor changes in the session, or when new frames arrive from the camera feed. These updates are not tied to any renderer. This means that you can implement these methods with a different renderer, like Metal, for example. You would only need to create an `ARSession` object and set its delegate.

Since both protocols extend from [ARSessionObserver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionobserver), I would say that you will almost always implement only `ARSCNViewDelegate` when you're using an `ARSCNView`. The only method that could possibly benefit you from `ARSessionDelegate` is [session(_:didUpdate:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session), which informs you about frame updates, and it seems that there is no equivalent in `ARSCNViewDelegate`. As for anchor updates, they will be reflected on `ARSCNViewDelegate` since SceneKit will update its scene based on ARKit events.

One last thing: `ARSCNView` is just a convenience class that Apple provided so you already have ARKit tied with a SceneKit renderer, but it would still be possible for you to implement your own `ARSession` with a custom `SCNScene`.